# Logcat is displaying my devices details

Tags: android, device, android-logcat

[image]> I am working on a application and trying to test my on my device

> (Samsung galaxy). but instead of showing errors and logs, it is
>   showing my mobiles details like temperature, ram etc etc and
>   contentiously displaying the same log again and again. what can I do. 
>   thank you for your important time in advance.

Answer (score 0):

From your IDE go to logcat and I think that your having the No Filters option, switch it to your app package name

like this

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You looks to be in `System Information` mode. If you are using `Monitor`, just pick your device in the left column and click on the `LogCat` tab in the bottom view.

[image]

If your are using `Eclipse`, click on `Window` -> `Show View` -> `Other` and then pick `LogCat` in the `Android` folder.
Then in the bottom view, change the `dropdown` value to `verbose`.